# How to make image rollover on jcarousel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jcarousel

I am using Jcarousel from http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/examples/ajax/ and it is working with no issues. How can I make the image rollover on mouse hover event? 
What is the js code needs to be implemented and where?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

based on the example given, there's a `div` called "jcarousel"
so on your page load after jcarousel has been initialized add something like

```
$('#jcarousel ul li img').hover(function(){
    //do what you want to do here
});
```